# WPF: Outook crash after drag and drop email form outlook (Office Interop)

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, office-interop

In my WPF application I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook to drag and drop emails in my application and process them.

But sporadically Outlook crashes after dropping an email. No exceptions are trown, all I can find is an App Crash statement in de Windows event log...

Any ideas what could be the cause?

```
    private void HandleDrop()
    {
        int mailItemsHandled = HandleMailItemDrop();
        SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(arg =>
        {
            if (mailItemsHandled > 1)
            {
                // do something
            }
            else if (mailItemsHandled == 1)
            {
                // do something
            }
        }), "null");
    }

 private int HandleMailItemDrop()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application Outlook = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;
        //new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        int mailItemsHandled = 0;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Explorer oExplorer = Outlook?.ActiveExplorer();
        if (oExplorer != null)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Selection oSelection = oExplorer.Selection;
            if (oSelection != null)
            {
                List<Email> items = new List<Email>();
                foreach (object item in oSelection)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = item as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;
                    if (mailItem != null)
                    {
                        Email email = // do some logic with the mailItem
                        items.Add(email);
                        mailItemsHandled++;
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItem);
                    }
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSelection);
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oExplorer);
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Outlook);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(Outlook);
        return mailItemsHandled;
    }
```

Comment: ``Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Outlook)`` and ``Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(Outlook)`` will throw exceptions on null. You wrote ``Outlook?.ActiveExplorer();`` so it seems you are excepting ``Outlook`` to be ``null`` because of the ``?.``.

Comment: its odd you talk of drag/drop and then use outlook to work out whats selected..

Comment: I use the PreviewDrop event from the WPF window to call the HandleDrop. So it's not a direct drag and drop. But that has nothing to do with the crashes.